# Using Ajax to load a TinyMCE text area

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, tinymce

**EDIT:**
After doing what [Kiran Kumara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2440399/kiran-kumara) suggested by adding 
`<div id="static_id></div>` 
to the end of "index.html.erb" and changing "edit.js.erb" to contain the following:

```
jQuery("div#static-id").html("<%=escape_javascript(render 'form')%>");
```

pressing the "Edit" links does indeed render the TinyMCE editors. However, the "regular" text_area is also loaded where the static-id div was placed in the index at the bottom of the page and edits can only be made from that text_area. How can I enable it so that only the TinyMCE editor appears and makes the actual edits?

---

I'm working on a very simple planner application and am trying to use Ajax to load an edit form into the index page. The only model in the project is the model "Day".  I followed [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised) rails cast but I haven't been able to get the form to load using Ajax. I am using TinyMCE as the text area in the edit form and am using the [tinymce-rails](https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails) gem to implement TinyMCE in my project. I continue to get "304 Not Modified" as the status of the GET requests.  when explicitly going to an object's edit path, I can get the TinyMCE text area to load.

I've been searching for hours for a solution but I either don't understand how to implement them or they're seriously outdated. From what I've read I'm thinking that this may have to do with the fact that the index page could potentially be calling multiple TinyMCE editors.  Could someone explain why this isn't working? Thank you! :)

Here are relevant code samples from my project:

**index.html.erb**

I have multiple dates shown in the index, which are displayed as a list in the view. These are the various instances of the "Day" model and each contains a to-do list of sorts. I'd like to be able to edit a list chosen from the index page.

```
<h1>Tasks</h1>

<ul class="tasks">
    <% @date_range.each do |day| %>
        <li class="<%= time_tense(day.date) %>">
            <%= render "display_tasks", day: day %>
        </li>
    <% end -%>
</ul>
```

**_display_tasks.html.erb**

```
<h2 id="daily_list_<%= day.id %>">
    <%= format_date(day.date) %>
</h2>

<% if day.tasks.blank? %>
    <p>No tasks specified</p>
<% else %>
    <%= raw day.tasks %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to "Edit", edit_day_path(day), id: "#{day.id}", remote: true %>

<%= tinymce %>
```

**edit.html.erb**

```
<h2 class="<%= time_tense(@day.date) %>" id="list_<%= @day.id %>">
    <%= format_date(@day.date) %>
</h2>
<%= render "form", day: @day %>
```

**edit.js.erb**

```
$("#edit_daily_list_<%= @day.id %>").hide().after('<%= j render(partial: "form") %>');
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for (@day, remote: true) do |f| %>
    <% if @day.errors.any? %>
      <div class="error_messages">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@day.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this task from being saved:</h2>
        <ul>
            <% @day.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
              <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.text_area :tasks, id: @day.id, class: "tinymce" %>

    <div class="actions">
        <p><%= f.submit "Update" %></p>
    </div>
<% end -%>

<%= tinymce %>
```

**days_controller.erb**

```
class DaysController < ApplicationController

    def index
        today = Day.find_by_date(Date.today)
        @date_range = date_range(today)
    end

    def show
        @day = Day.find(params[:id])
    end

    def edit
        @day = Day.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @day = Day.find(params[:id])
        if @day.update_attributes(params[:day])
            redirect_to day_path(@day)
        else
            redirect_to edit_day_path(@day)
        end
    end

    private
        def date_range(days=7, today)
            future_dates = []
            past_dates = []

            (1..days).to_a.each do |day|
                future_dates.push Day.find_by_date(today.date.advance days:  day)
                past_dates.unshift Day.find_by_date(today.date.advance days: -day)
            end

            [future_dates.reverse, today, past_dates.reverse].flatten
        end
end
```

Comment: are you able to get the js response in your console?.

Comment: Hrm, I've been messing around with it and I'm currently getting a 500 Internal Server error when clicking Edit

Comment: The first line of my form in _form.html.erb read: <%= form_for (@day, remote: true) do |f| %>. I removed the remote parameter and I get the nothing in my console as before when I had written the question.

Comment: I can't see #edit_daily_list_(number) id any where in your file.

Comment: Gah sorry I did a last minute changing of variables. I must not have caught that. I replaced all (or so I thought) instances of "daily_list" to "day" so that I would have fewer variables.

Comment: Upon closer inspection it appears that I should have simply $(<%= @day.id =>)... instead in "edit.js.erb". No response in the console as of yet though, even with that change.

Comment: Please do one thing put static div in your _display_tasks.html.erb 
<div id = "static-id"> </div>
and 

in edit.js.erb put this

jQuery("div#static-id").html("<%=escape_javascript(render 'form')%>");

and see is it replacing the div with form and the editor.

Comment: Should the div in _display_tasks.html.erb encompass the entire partial?

Comment: I think an issue with that would be having multiple id's of "static-id" since _display_tasks is rendered for all of the days displayed in the index page. This was why I was trying to use the day.id to have a unique id for each edit link being displayed on the page

Comment: sorry put that static div in index.html.erb at last, and try.

Comment: This works! Although the update button isn't being displayed, the form is showing up dynamically. Thank you! What is the next step?

Comment: Actually the update button IS being displayed. Sorry about that. I just need to make sure that the regular text area is not. This is such a relief. I've been pulling out my hair all day with this problem. Why was this happening? Thank you again :)

Comment: I suppose that the only issue now is that there are 2 text boxes being displayed. tinyMCE and the regular text_area. Updates will only go through if I type into the regular text_area

Comment: I have updated the main post. Again, thank you so much for helping me out :)